# Почему отвалился mysql после переключения в apache2 php 8.1 до php 8.0?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, битрикс

на ubuntu установлен lamp, возникла потребность установить 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом. На php 8.1 эту чудесная CMS не работает вылетает ошибка Fatal error: $GLOBALS can only be modified using the $GLOBALS[$name] = $value syntax in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/tools.php on line 4054.

Нашел у ответы в google что это чудо не устанавливается на php 8.1, надо переключить в apache2 до версии php 8.0. Установщик запустился но отвалился mysql. Что надо где прописать чтобы mysql заработал? Помогите пожалуйста)[image: вывод phpinfo()]

Comment: расширение mysql для 8.0 нужно устанавливать отдельно. Вы скрин привели для 8.1, хотя сами же написали что нужна 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфигурация php 8.0 лежит в отдельном каталоге от php 8.1 и использует отдельные модули.

Нужно установить php8.0-mysql и включить его в конфигурации.

php8.0 нет в пакетах убунту, можно добавить через ppa [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.0-mysql
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, дай вам бог!!!